# How to fix links after importing a PPT onto iPad's Keynote?

Tags: ipad, keynote, ms-office

After I transferred my Power Point presentations onto my new iPad, into Keynote, I notice a problem. The links associated with buttons within a Power Point slide to connect to other slides in the presentation are no longer working, but everything else is?

Is there an easy fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keynote for iPad doesn't support links inside the presentation itself (per Apple's [Keynote for iPad FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4066)). Or at least it doesn't currently; KN/iPad is already a lot better than it was when it first shipped.